# How to find out size of a PhotoImage in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

How do I access the width and height information on a `PhotoImage()` class object?
I tried `PhotoImage(...).winfo_width()` and `PhotoImage(...)["Width"]`. Both of them didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PhotoImage objects have a `width` and `height` method:

```
import Tkinter as tk

image_data = '''
    R0lGODlhEAAQAMQZAMPDw+zs7L+/v8HBwcDAwLW1teLi4t7e3uDg4MLCwuHh4e7u7t/f38TExLa2
    tre3t7i4uL6+vu/v77q6uu3t7b29vby8vLm5ubu7u+3t7QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEA
    ABkALAAAAAAQABAAAAWNYCaOZFlWV6pWZlZhTQwAyYSdcGRZGGYNE8vo1RgYCD2BIkK43DKXRsQg
    oUQiFAkCI3iILgCLIEvJBiyQiOML6GElVcsFUllD25N3FQN51L81b2ULARN+dhcDFggSAT0BEgcQ
    FgUicgQVDHwQEwc+DxMjcgITfQ8Pk6AlfBEVrjuqJhMOtA4FBRctuiUhADs=
'''

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_data)
dimensions = "image size: %dx%d" % (image.width(), image.height())
label = tk.Label(root, compound="top", image=image, text=dimensions)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possibly `tkinter` bug. Better use `PIL`/`Pillow` `Image` and `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead of just `tk.PhotoImage`

```
In [30]: import tkinter as tk
In [31]: from PIL import Image, ImageTk

In [32]: tk_img = tk.PhotoImage('./pixel-art-2237058.gif')
In [35]: tk_img.width()
Out[35]: 0

In [36]: pil_img = Image.open('./pixel-art-2237058.gif')
In [37]: tk_pil_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)
In [39]: tk_pil_img.width()
Out[39]: 811
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
In [32]: tk_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='./pixel-art-2237058.gif')
```

Comment: This works like a charm. This hard requirement of file=... is counter-intuitive to C programmers.